# Append array using apr_array_push in D

Tags: c, svn, segmentation-fault, d, apr

I am writing a program in the D that uses svn and I came across something I can not figure out how to convert into D syntax. I took a stab at it but it segfaults.

Example of what I am trying to accomplish in C:

```
svn_auth_provider_object_t provider;
providers = apr_array_make(pool, 1, sizeof(svn_auth_provider_object_t*));
svn_auth_get_simple_provider2(&provider, null, null, pool);
*(svn_auth_provider_object_t**)apr_array_push (providers) = provider;
svn_auth_open(&auth_baton, providers, pool);
```

As far as I know, this code works just fine. I have found several examples done almost exactly the same way.
Here is my attempt to copy this in D:

```
svn_auth_provider_object_t provider;
providers = apr_array_make(pool, 1, svn_auth_provider_object_t.sizeof);
svn_auth_get_simple_provider2(&provider, null, null, pool);
void* newSlot = apr_array_push(m);
newSlot = provider;
svn_auth_open(&auth_baton, providers, pool);
```

This throws a Segmentation Fault on svn_auth_open.
My best guess is that the contents of provider are not ending up at the pointer held by newSlot. And I am not sure why that is.

Supplemental code:

```
/// Code taken from Apache's APR libary which is licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0

struct apr_array_header_t {
    apr_pool_t* pool;
    int elt_size;
    int nelts;
    int nalloc;
    char* elts;
};

struct svn_auth_provider_object_t
{
    svn_auth_provider_t *vtable;
    void *provider_baton;
}

APR_DECLARE(void *) apr_array_push(apr_array_header_t *arr)
{
    if (arr->nelts == arr->nalloc) {
        int new_size = (arr->nalloc <= 0) ? 1 : arr->nalloc * 2;
        char *new_data;

        new_data = apr_palloc(arr->pool, arr->elt_size * new_size);

        memcpy(new_data, arr->elts, arr->nalloc * arr->elt_size);
        memset(new_data + arr->nalloc * arr->elt_size, 0,
               arr->elt_size * (new_size - arr->nalloc));
        arr->elts = new_data;
        arr->nalloc = new_size;
    }

    ++arr->nelts;
    return arr->elts + (arr->elt_size * (arr->nelts - 1));
}

#define APR_ARRAY_IDX(ary,i,type) (((type *)(ary)->elts)[i])
#define APR_ARRAY_PUSH(ary,type) (*((type *)apr_array_push(ary)))

void
svn_auth_open(svn_auth_baton_t **auth_baton,
              apr_array_header_t *providers,
              apr_pool_t *pool)
{
  svn_auth_baton_t *ab;
  svn_auth_provider_object_t *provider;
  int i;

  /* Build the auth_baton. */
  ab = apr_pcalloc(pool, sizeof(*ab));
  ab->tables = apr_hash_make(pool);
  ab->parameters = apr_hash_make(pool);
  ab->creds_cache = apr_hash_make(pool);
  ab->pool = pool;

  /* Register each provider in order.  Providers of different
     credentials will be automatically sorted into different tables by
     register_provider(). */
  for (i = 0; i < providers->nelts; i++)
    {
      provider_set_t *table;
      provider = APR_ARRAY_IDX(providers, i, svn_auth_provider_object_t *);

      /* Add it to the appropriate table in the auth_baton */
      table = apr_hash_get(ab->tables,
                           provider->vtable->cred_kind, APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
      if (! table)
        {
          table = apr_pcalloc(pool, sizeof(*table));
          table->providers
            = apr_array_make(pool, 1, sizeof(svn_auth_provider_object_t *));

          apr_hash_set(ab->tables,
                       provider->vtable->cred_kind, APR_HASH_KEY_STRING,
                       table);
        }
      APR_ARRAY_PUSH(table->providers, svn_auth_provider_object_t *)
        = provider;
    }

  *auth_baton = ab;
}
```

My best guess is that the segfault is happening in APR_ARRAY_IDX. Everything else has a valid memory address.

Additional information:
This doesn't work either:

```
providers = apr_array_make(pool, 1, svn_auth_provider_object_t.sizeof);
svn_auth_provider_object_t* newSlot = cast(svn_auth_provider_object_t*) apr_array_push(providers);
svn_auth_get_simple_provider2(&newSlot, null, null, pool);
svn_auth_open(&auth_baton, providers, pool);
```

So that rules out my theory that the data wasn't going to the right place. However if I comment out the array push line and just send the array empty it works fine.
So, this does not segfault:

```
providers = apr_array_make(pool, 1, svn_auth_provider_object_t.sizeof);
svn_auth_open(&auth_baton, providers, pool);
```

I also know it is not svn_auth_get_simple_provider2 because this segfaults as well...

```
providers = apr_array_make(pool, 1, svn_auth_provider_object_t.sizeof);
svn_auth_provider_object_t* newSlot = cast(svn_auth_provider_object_t*) apr_array_push(providers);
svn_auth_get_ssl_server_trust_file_provider(&newSlot, pool);
svn_auth_open(&auth_baton, providers, pool);
```

Comment: As way to definitevly track down the segfault, gdb version 7.2 should work with D. So, if you compile with `-gc` and have core dumps enabled, then you should be able to see what is causing the segfault by using gdb.

Comment: I am new to writing programs that compile down to machine language. So I am not familiar with gdb, I am trying to use it but it didn't expect it to work well with D. All I have figured out to do thus far is to backtrace.

Comment: auto is not a type. It allows for inferring the type, since the compiler knows what type is returned from the function. The type can not be change, and you can find out what it is with typeid(var).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, the first assignment to newSlot is dead as the next line overwrites it, setting it to `null`. Try:

```
auto newSlot = cast(svn_auth_provider_object_t**)apr_array_push(m);
*newSlot = provider;
```

This would have resulted in a compile time error if it hadn't been `void*`.

I think the only part of the C version that isn't valid D is the cast.

Comment: And that worked! Even though I left the `m' variable in there by mistake. I am going to do some more looking into this `auto' type. I saw it before but I see it would be helpful to understand it completely. Any resources you can suggest would be appreciated since D documentation seems sparse.

Comment: @Jacks_Depression: auto is just a place holder (const or immutable would also work). The general form is that a the type can be omitted from a declaration-and-initialization and it is assumed to be the type of the things being assigned to it: http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/declaration.html#AutoDeclaration